# How to use the useEffect function in react js chart 2 to change the labels?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I have module where I need use the date range in react js chart 2 to filter the data based on start and end of that date. The problem right now is I have already the date it's working however the date that I filter is not take effect on the labels of chart. **Ex: Default Range From : 2021-06-09 To: 2021-06-24** and I want to change that date **From: 2021-06-24 To: 2021-07-01**

Here is the output:

[image]

as you can see nothing change but I already filter it. I don't know if my useEffect or my useState is wrong. Please I need your suggestion and comments to solve the problem.

UseState:

```
const [chartData, setChartData] = useState({})

const [selectionRange, setSelectionRange] = useState({
    startDate: new Date(Date.now() - 15 * 24*60*60*1000),
    endDate: new Date(),
    key: "selection"
})
```

dateDate:

```
const dataDate = (props_range) => {

    

    var date = new Date(), y = date.getFullYear(), m = date.getMonth();

    var firstDay = new Date(y, m, 1);

    var lastDay = new Date(y, m + 1, 0);
    
    var month = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]

    var dDate = []

    var startDate = props_range.startDate;
    var endDate =  props_range.endDate;

    console.log(startDate);
    console.log(endDate);

    let formatted_date = '';
    

    var from = new Date(startDate);
    var to = new Date(endDate);
        
    // loop for every day
    for (var day = from; day <= to; day.setDate(day.getDate() + 1)) {
        var date = new Date(day);
        console.log(date);
        //formatted_date = month[date.getMonth()] + " " + date.getDate();     
        dDate.push(date);
    }
   

    return dDate

}
```

useEffect:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    setChartData({
        labels: dataDate(selectionRange),
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'Receive Check',
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(195 218 251 / 35%)',
                borderColor: '#70a8f3',
                pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                pointBorderWidth: '2',
                fill: true,
                lineTension: 0.0,
                pointRadius: 7,
                borderWidth: 1,
                data: randomVal(),
            }
        ]
    })

}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

`selectionRange` is a state, thus it needs to be included in dependency array:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setChartData({
        labels: dataDate(selectionRange),
        // ...
    })

}, [selectionRange]);
```